# how should i arrange my code to fix error CS1022

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement

i was using unity to learn 2d game development, and i just got started with coding and game develompment.
i encountered the Error:CS1022 Type or namespace definition, or end-of-life expected
here is the code i've written:

`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

{public class Player : MonoBehaviour
public Rigidbody2D rb;
public int movespeed;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() { 
     rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2 (-movespeed, rb.velocity.y);
    }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2 (movespeed, rb.velocity.y);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2 (rb.velocity.x, 5);
    }
    
public Transform groundCheck;
public float groundCheckRadius;
public LayerMask whatIsGround;
public bool onGround;

     void FixedUpdate()
     {
        onGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position,
        groundCheckRadius,whatIsGround);
     }
}
}
```

`
i was trying to make a control for my game character's jumping ability so that it couldn't fly by jumping.

it says that the error is at the line (39,1). i can't figure out how to fix this error can anyone help and explain what i was doing wrong?

i didn't know what to do since i had followed exactly how the book i'm using to learn coding says, and i've tried rearanging the code but to no avail.

Comment: I do not know if you pasted the code correctly but it seems that you have some redundant "}" in the end of your code.

Comment: I think you missing an closing "}" for "Update()"-Method

Comment: Code formatting really does help you keep track or things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most useful skills in programming is learning how to interpret compilation errors. The error you have says "Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected" - what the compiler is saying is that it thought it reached the end of the file, but there was more stuff at the end that it doesn't know how to interpret.

But the important part here is knowing that what the compiler uses to work out where it thinks things should start and end is the use of curly brackets `{` and `}`, which delimit the start and end of things like classes, namespaces and other blocks (like if/else/for/foreach/etc). So if you get an error like the one you're seeing, chances are your curly brackets aren't in the correct place, or they don't match.

So if you count your curly brackets, you've got 7 `{`'s and 7 `}`'s, which is good - you haven't opened something and then forgotten to close it. So the problem is the placement of the curly brackets

If you look closely your class starts like this:

```
{public class Player : MonoBehaviour
public Rigidbody2D rb;
```

Which looks wrong - when defining a block, you specify the block and *then* put the curly brackets afterwards. So you're defining a class, but you've put the curly bracket in the wrong place. To define a class, you do the following:

```
protectionlevel class ClassName : SuperClass, IInterface {
    // content of the class goes here
}
```

So for your class, you wanted a public class with name `Player` that inherits from `MonoBehaviour`, with no interfaces, so it should be this:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    // content of the class goes here
}
```

There also is another curly bracket error with the code for the update function - here's the entire contents of the update method (from start curly to end curly) is this:

```
    void Update() { // starts here
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2 (-movespeed, rb.velocity.y);
    }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2 (movespeed, rb.velocity.y);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2 (rb.velocity.x, 5);
    }
    
public Transform groundCheck;
public float groundCheckRadius;
public LayerMask whatIsGround;
public bool onGround;

     void FixedUpdate()
     {
        onGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position,
        groundCheckRadius,whatIsGround);
     }
} // ends here
```

Which probably isn't what you intended. The fields `groundCheck` etc and the method `FixedUpdate` should be defined outside of your `Update` function. Try closing the `Update` function after your `if` statements, so that the following code is defined as part of the class, rather than the `Update` method.

The best way of seeing the curly bracket errors is by following a consistent [indentation style](https://csharp.2000things.com/2013/11/01/965-indent-code-to-improve-readability/) of indenting one level per curly bracket. That way you'll easily see what is part of a class or function or whatever, and help you debug these sorts of issues.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out in the comments, there are several formatting errors in your code, such as an extra opening bracket `{` before the class declaration and a missing closing bracket `}` for the `Update` method.

If you're working with an IDE such as Visual Studio, there's formatting options built in (`Edit > Advanced > Format Document`) which will help you organise the bracket indentations; although they won't auto-resolve the errors

Here's your code, but more formatted:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    
    public bool onGround;
    public float groundCheckRadius;
    public int movespeed;
    
    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-movespeed, rb.velocity.y);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(movespeed, rb.velocity.y);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 5);
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        onGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position,
            groundCheckRadius, whatIsGround);
    }
}
```

I've moved the variables to the top, so they're easily distinguishable from the rest of the code and added a `private` access modifier to the built-in Unity functions.

Comment: Thank you for your help. i fixed the problem and now my game character can jump